# How edit or correct a Bazaar commit comment?

Tags: bazaar

After executing `bzr commit`, is there a way to edit the comment associated with the commit?

For example, suppose I used the following Bazaar command:

```
bzr commit -m "Some comment wit spelng errorz."
```

Is there a way to correct the comment associated to the commit to read:

```
"Some comment with spelling corrections."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bzr uncommit` will undo the commit but keep the files in the same state, so you can then make a new commit with the correct message.

Comment: bzr uncommit solves the problem, but I thought I could make additional code changes before re-commiting the revision, and this resulted in merge issues.  I've added a note about that in the answer.

Comment: @PJSingh, merge conflicts stem from other people making changes between the time you pull and push: they are unrelated to making a commit and going back and modifying that commit before you finally push.